# conversion constructor or copy constructor

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand conversion constructors. I am using the following piece of code

```
class cls 
{
public:
  cls()
  {
      std::cout << "Regular constructor \n";     ---> Line A
  }
  cls (int a) //Constructing converter
  {
      std::cout << "Int constructor \n";         ---> Line B
  }

  cls (cls& d) //Copy constructor
  {
      std::cout << "Copy constructor \n";        ---> Line C
  }
};


int main()
{
    cls d;
    std::cout << "-----------------------\n";
    cls e = 15; //int constructor then copy constructor
        return;
}
```

Now I am confused at the statement `cls e = 15` my understanding was that this statement was suppose to call Line B(Conversion Cont) and then Line C (Copy constructor) however it only called Line B. I though `cls e = 15` was equivalent to `cls e = cls(15)`. So I tried `cls e = cls(15)` which also only gives the Line B. I would appreciate it if someone could explain what happens when we use the following

`cls e = cls(15)` //I was expecting a conversion constructor followed by copy constructor  but apparently i was wrong. Any explanation on what is happening would be appreciated

Comment: sorry let me correct it

Comment: The compiler is free to elide unnecessary copies. You're right, in practice the copy constructor would get called.

Comment: Remarks: `cls (cls& d)` should probably be `cls (const cls& d)` (or `cls (cls const& d)`), and `return;` should certainly be `return 0;`.

Comment: Is the code really as presented? In particular, does the copy constructor really take a non-const reference? If so, then the code should not compile in the first place!

Comment: Yes the code does compile VS2010

Comment: @Rajeshwar It only compiles because of an "evil" compiler extension (and should give you a warning with level `/W4` or `/Wall`). With G++ (after fixing the `return 0;`, commenting line comments and adding `#include <iostream>`): http://ideone.com/79IAs0 (vs http://ideone.com/cpAB6G )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to **[copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)** compiler optimization. An compiler is allowed to elide copy constructor calls in certain cases. What you see is this optimization in action. You are right in assuming calls to:

- Conversion constructor and then a
- Copy constructor

But in this case the second call is elided/removed/optimized by the constructor by using return value optimization. The compiler constructs the object directly in to `e` rather than creating a temporary object and then copying it to `e`.

If you are using GCC you can use `-fno-elide-constructors` option to disable copy-elision and you should see the result you expected.

Comment: This would be correct, except that the code is ill-formed and should not compile. While the compiler is allowed to elide the copy, it must verify the availability of the copy constructor, even if it is elided. In this case, the copy constructor has the peculiarity that it takes the argument by non-const reference, which makes the program incorrect.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: True, The copy constructor should be available and accessible as well. Probably OP missed the `const` on the copy ctor argument while copy pasting the code.

Comment: Quick question so does this mean that the statement `cls a; cls c =a` mean `cls c = cls(a)` so actually first the copy constructor of cls(a) is called then another copy constructor for `cls c` is called ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Yes. But as I said above copy elision can elide the excessive copy constructor calls which generate temporary useless copies.

Comment: Any idea how we can temporarily disable it in VS2010 ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: AFAIK, there is no way to do so in VS.

Comment: @Rajeshwar @AlokSave "does this mean that the statement `cls a; cls c =a` mean `cls c = cls(a)`": _No_, because here `a` and `c` have _the same type_ (which wasn't the case for `cls e = 15;`), so `cls c = a;` is the same as `cls c(a);` (except if the copy constructor were `explicit`, in which case `cls c = a;` wouldn't compile). So, with `-fno-elide-constructors` to disable copy elision, `cls c = cls(a);` would call the copy constructor twice, but `cls c = a;` will always call it only once. (I have verified it.)

Comment: @Gx_ I agree I just tried this on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/  with `-fno-elide-constructors` and this only happens when they are of different types

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the compiler is optimising your code not ot call the copy constructor which is known as `copy elision`

Please look [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) for more details.

Basically in copy elision a compiler optimizez your code to omit unnessesary intermediate temporary objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about that `cls e = 15` is the same as `cls e = cls(15)`. This is because your `cls(int a)` is not declared explicit. Next is just compiler copy elision optimization.

Comment: `This is because your cls(int a) is not declared explicit` - it has nothing to do with it being declared `explicit` or not.

Comment: I think if we had `explicit cls(int a)` then `cls t = 15` would not compile. `error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘cls’ requested`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It has very much to do with it.  If the constructor is declared explicit, then this will compile: `cls e(15);` -- But this will not: `cls e = 15;`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I know, but that's not the reason the copy constructor isn't called.